# take snapshots every second using artist animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use this function:

```
def Plot(data):

    plt.colormaps()
    n=sc.shape(data)[2]
    ims=[]
    for i in range(n):
        mydata=data[:,:,i]
        im=plt.imshow(mydata,cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
        ims.append([im])
    return ims
```

and call it like:

```
fig=plt.gcf()
ani=ArtistAnimation(fig,result,interval=10,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

I want to ask if it possible to take snapshots of the plot(animation)  for every 1 second for example.

(I use matplotlib)

Comment: I guess you'r not getting an answer, because you didn't provide sufficient context-information to your question. For starters: Which framework are you using? Matplotlib?

Comment: @Don Question:Yes,matplotlib.I have it as a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `ArtistAnimation` and overwrite the _step - method, e.g.:

```
class SnapShotAnimation(ArtistAnimation):
    def __init__(self, fig, artists, snapshot_delay, *args, **kwargs):
        self._snapshot_delay = snapshot_delay
        self._time_to_snapshot = snapshot_delay
        ArtistAnimation.__init__(self, fig, artists, *args, **kwargs)

    def _step(self, *args):
        if self._time_to_snapshot <= 0:
            do_snapshot() 
            self._time_to_snapshot = self._snap_shot_delay #reset timer
        else:
            self._time_to_snapshot -= self._interval
        ArtistAnimation._step(*args) #ancestor method maybe better at start

    def do_snapshot(self):
        """Your actual snapshot code comes here - basically saving to a output"""
        fname = 'snapshot.png'
        self._fig.savefig(fname)
```

adding:

```
snapshot_delay = 1000 # time in ms
```

changing:

```
ani=SnapShotAnimation(fig,result,snapshot_delay, interval=10,repeat=False)
```

in your example source.

For better understanding what and how to do, i would recommend to take a look into the [matplotlib sources](http://fossies.org/dox/matplotlib-1.1.0/animation_8py_source.html).

Comment: :Hello,i don't understand what to put in "do_snapshot".If i run this it gives me "__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)" . Also, put a comma in the arguments in init (...snapshot_delay,*args..).Thanks!

Comment: :It continues to give me "__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)".

Comment: Yeah, the inherited constructor call was incomplete. I can't and won't provide a complete solution, just wanted to lend a hand in getting you started. Keep in mind, that my `do_snapshot` mehthod is an example and you have to modify it to fit your needs.